# How to call touchesBegan in a sub-classed UIView in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I want `touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to be called in a sub-classed `UIView`.

**AppDelegate.m**:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [self.window setRootViewController:[[UIViewController alloc] init]];

    CGRect firstFrame = self.window.bounds;
    HypnosisView *firstView = [[SubClassedView alloc] initWithFrame:firstFrame];

    [self.window addSubview:firstView];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**SubClassedView.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SubClassedView : UIView

@end
```

**SubClassedView.m**:

```
#import "SubClassedView.h"

@implementation SubClassedView

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Here!");
}

@end
```

When I touched the screen, the console didn't output "Here!" as I thought it should.

I use the newest Xcode 7 beta 5.

How can I get `touchesBegan` to be called in the right way?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding your `HypnosisView` as the subview of the window, rather than as a subview of the root view controller's view. Your root view controller should be a `UIViewController` *subclass* so that you can modify its behaviour to build your app's navigation flow.

Subclass `UIViewController`, and add your `HypnosisView` as a subview in its view hierarchy:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic, strong) HypnosisView *hypnosisView;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.hypnosisView = [[HypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:hypnosisView];
}

@end
```

Then in your app delegate, set your view controller subclass to be the root view controller:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    MyViewController *myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:myVC];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

This is quite an old-school method of doing things though. Is there any reason you're not using storyboards to build your interface?

Comment: I'm learning iOS development with an "old" book (published at 2014). I know the book is a little outdated, I still want to finish it though. Thanks!

Comment: @Vayn Fair enough, there's no harm in learning how to do things the old way (mind you 2014 isn't _that_ old!). In fact, it can be quite beneficial in the long run :).